# JQuery sends multiple request while clicking submit button multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a code in code-igniter project. 
Where I'm sending a query to controller ,
It should execute only one time . But when I click multiple times on submit button , it adds the same product which is got from jquery multiple times. 
For example, I chose a product "phone" which costs $5 . When I click submit button , 3 times it adds 3 "phone" product and it costs $15 . 
I tried to disable to "add-to-cart" button , tried to hide it when clicking, 
But it takes so much of time to load. 
Here's my code .

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var n = 0;
    $( "#add-to-cart" ).one( "click", function() {
        var index = $( "#add-to-cart" ).index( this );
        $( this ).css({
            borderStyle: "inset",
            cursor: "auto"
         });
    });
});
```

```html
<input id="add-to-cart" type="submit" value="ADD TO CART">
```

Comment: Hmmm but would it be business logic to want to disable such? If so, maybe we could use a product id type to first check your list if it already exists and decide through that if should add or not? Then you wouldn't need to worry about disabling the button

Comment: Inside the button's callback, disable the button by adding a CSS class of `{pointer-event:none;}`

Comment: It's a normal behaviour; you may check for conditions you need

Comment: @ScottMarcus could you please explain it clearly?

Comment: Create a CSS class like this:  `.disable {pointer-events:none;}` and in the button's event handler add the class like this: `this.classList.add("disable");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to declare a control variable and check its state when you add to cart?

```
var added = false;
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var n = 0;
    $( "#add-to-cart" ).one( "click", function()
    {
      if (!added)
      {
          var index = $( "#add-to-cart" ).index( this );
          $( this ).css({
              borderStyle: "inset",
              cursor: "auto"
          });
          added = true;
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Will try this one.